# Can we please see the uncompiled JavaScript source for runtime.js?

Tags: google-swiffy

Seeing the readable source would make it much easier to use Swiffy as part of a more complete Flash substitute/alternative.

Comment: Hear, hear.  It seems so unlike typical openness of Google.  I seem to recall that Swiffy compiler got its start based on another open source Java-based swf parser.  If so, perhaps that might be a good starting point for creating an alternative.  I really like the workflow that Swiffy Extension provides, and animated svg performs ok, but relying on an online compiler seems risky or short-sighted.

Answer (score 1):

Use a javascript beautifier like this : http://jsbeautifier.org/
Just copy and paste the runtime.js code. Also its not compiled. It's been through a javascript minimizer.